# Neo4j Graph DB: How to do time-based datamodelling for User->SecurityHoldings relationship

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j Graph database and I am trying to do data-modelling of below User Investment holding information into the Graph DB:

I have a User entity:

```
(n:User)
{
  "user_id": "1000001", "account_number":"1234500"
}
```

And a Securities entity:

```
(n:Security)
{
  "security_id": "12001", "cusip_number":"NH0000909", "ISIN":"US61760X7782"
}
```

And I have a relationship between those 2 entities:

```
(User {"user_id": "1000001"})-[:HOLDS {quatity: 150}]->(Security {"security_id": "12001"})
```

It looks like this in Graphical format:
[image]

Now here is the major problem in this data model:

1. This relationship between the User and Securities is dynamic over time. Meaning the Security Quantity a User holds changes each day. But in above Graph the Quantity is fixed so some way needs to be added to show Quantity changing everyday for User's Securities.
2. There is another relationship between Security and DailyPrice. Meaning each Security's price will change each day. So how can I model this history information too? :

   (Security {"security_id": "12001"})-[:HAS]->(DailyPrice {date: 10/22/2018, price: 55.20, currency: USD})

Could you please help me with the correct data-modelling so that above 2 problems can be solved?

Comment: How is quantity determined? Do you need a historical record or just the current state? (1) is only a problem if you need the history, and (2) is stated as a fact, not a problem. In what way is your current model failing you?

Comment: Hi @Tezra. Ofcourse as the title of this Question suggests, this is a Time based or History based data modelling problem. And yes I updated #2 so that it clearly states that both #1 and #2 requires storing History information for each Day i.e. in #1 I want Quatity information for each day and for #2 I want Seurity Price for each day.